# Capturar valores e imprimir en tabla

Tags: php, array, formularios

Aqui estoy capturando la informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego el problema viene para decir el limite de productos es decir solo quiero que haga el recorrido depende de cuantos productos hayan en el formulario, pero hace el recorrido de cada campo repitiendose y elevandose, entonces lo que quiero es que solo tome la cantidad de productos

```
<div class="privacy about">
  <h3>Revi<span>sa tu compra</span></h3>
  <?php
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $total_prod=(count($_POST));
  }
  ?>
        <div class="checkout-right">
                  <h4>Su carrito de compras tiene: <span><?php echo $total_prod; ?> Productos</span></h4>

              <table class="timetable_sub">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Item.</th>
                          <th>Precio</th>
                          <th>Producto</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                      <?php
                      for ($i=1; $i<=$total_prod; $i++)
                      { ?>

                      <tr class="rem<?php echo $i ?>">
                      <td class="invert"><?php echo $i ?></td>
                      <td class="invert">
                           <div class="quantity">
                              <div class="quantity-select">

                                  <?php echo $_POST["precio_".$i]." $"; ?>

                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="invert"><?php echo $_POST["nombre_de_producto_".$i]; ?></td>
                      <td class="invert"><?php echo $_POST["cantidad_del_producto_".$i]; ?></td>

                          </div>

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                      <?php  } ?>
              </tbody></table>
          </div>
```

Teniendo como resultado el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los valores que viajan en el $_POST, aqui se puede ver que esta sumando los 6 valores y por eso a la hora de imprimir la tabla da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Eso es por que cuentas la cantidad de parámetros _POST que estas enviando, esta tabla sera rellenada desde una base de datos?
Si en ese caso los resultados los traerás mediante una base de datos generarías la consulta y luego si generarías un count a dicha consulta.

```
$total_product=count($query);
```

Podrías explicar como pasarías la lista de productos? si en caso de llegar a pasar manualmente parámetro por parámetro con _#Numero simplemente envía un parámetro mas con listado e iguala la cantidad

```
$total_product=$_POST['cantidad'];
```

Comment: No, por ahora no trabaja con base de datos, captura los valores desde un formulario desde minicart al darle añadir a los botones carga la información y luego al ser enviado por el metodo POST llega de esta manera
`Array ( [cantidad_del_producto_1] => 1 [nombre_de_producto_1] => Minions [precio_1] => 11 [cantidad_del_producto_2] => 4 [nombre_de_producto_2] => Ted 2 [precio_2] => 15 )`